# Как в Repository к запросу добавить окончание, которое приходит извне (в аргументах)?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

У меня в Spring Boot приложении в Repository есть методы, совершающие стандартные crud-операции. Но мне нужен дополнительно еще один метод, который будет запрашивать из БД данные в зависимости от условий. Например, есть 3 условия, они могут прийти в запросе все вместе или одно, или два из них. Я сделала класс QueryBuilder (возвращает String), который проверяет, что пришло, и в зависимости от этого составляет "хвост" запроса, начиная с WHERE. К примеру, если пришел только параметр name, то в QueryBuilder у меня будет "WHERE name LIKE '%name%'".
Этот QueryBuilder  я передаю в метод Repository. Вопрос в том, как там его прикрепить к началу запроса.
Сейчас в Repository у меня такой код:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT Person FROM Person :queryTail", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Person> findPersons(String queryTail);
```

Но он не работает. Как правильно добавить окончание к запросу?

Comment: Могу посоветовать 2 вещи: 1. включить логирование sql запросов ( тогда станет понятно, какое квери сгенерировала spring-data и что пошло не так). 2. Переделать данный метод с использованием criteria api (более удобно использовать, когда к запросу необходимо добавить динамические фильтры)

Comment: Большое спасибо!